# How to insert the whole editform into a div

Tags: list-form

I'm trying to insert an edit form created using sharepoint designer into a collapsible div.

As the form is in xsl format, how do I insert the form into my [collapsible div](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php)?

Thanks

Comment: The form is still a page, so use an iframe or load the page contents into the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your edit form created in SharePoint designer, you should find the List Form:

```
<div>
    <span id="part1">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
    </span>
    <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
    <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
</div>
```

You could warp those code inside your collapsible div.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't knew this part contains the whole edit form, I'd wrap this part in my div and solve the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope that helps..